# How to properly throw an error from the promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have one function, which returns Promise:

```js
  updatePassword(currentPassword: string, newPassword: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.fireAuth.currentUser.then((user: firebase.User) => {
      if (user) {
        const credentials = auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, currentPassword)

        user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials).then(res => {
          if (res) {
            user.updatePassword(newPassword)
          }
        }).catch(err => {
          throw new Error(err)
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

I call it inside another component:

```js
this.userService.updatePassword(currentPassword, newPassword).then(() => {
        console.log('successfully')
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error')
      })
```

But even when `updatePassword()` return Error, the function call in component still console log 'successfully' from 'then`. How to properly throw an error in my case?

Comment: what does `user.updatePassword` do? What do you mean by "return Error"? does it throw or return an error?

Comment: use `Promise.reject()` to throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to return your inner promise. Like this:

```
updatePassword(currentPassword: string, newPassword: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.fireAuth.currentUser.then((user: firebase.User) => {
      if (user) {
        const credentials = auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, currentPassword)

       return user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials).then(res => {
          if (res) {
            user.updatePassword(newPassword)
          }
        }).catch(err => {
          throw new Error(err)
        })
      }

      throw new Error('USER_NOT_FOUND')
    })
  }
```

**Edit:**
I also added `throw` if you do not get `user` as safety net.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your function to use `async`/`await`, and you don't need to manually throw anything.

You may wish to make those `return false`s some sort of `throw` too.

```
  async updatePassword(currentPassword: string, newPassword: string): Promise<void> {
    const user = await this.fireAuth.currentUser;
    if(!user) return false;
    const credentials = auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, currentPassword);
    const res = await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials);
    if(!res) return false;
    user.updatePassword(newPassword);
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `fireAuth` call fails, then throw a `Error` from the `updatePassword` `catch` block.

Check the working snippet attached.

```js
let fireAuth = (pass = false) => {
  if (pass) return Promise.resolve("passed");
  return Promise.reject("failed");
};

function updatePassword(shouldPass = false) {
  if (!shouldPass) {
    return fireAuth(false)
      .then(console.log)
      .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err in fireauth', err)
      throw new Error('OOPS')
    });
  }
  return Promise.resolve("success");
}

let failedResult = updatePassword()
  .then()
  .catch((err) => console.log("failedresult error", err.toString()));

let successResult = updatePassword(true)
  .then((res) => console.log("res is", res))
  .catch();
```